# Using L-BFGS optimizer with Tensorflow estimator API

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am using Tensorflow Estimator API but haven't figured out how to use the L-BFGS optimizer available at `tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface`.

It seems the estimator API expects some optimizer from the `tf.train` module but no BFGS implementation is available there. The only one defined in `contrib` does not follow the same interface.

To be more specific, in the [official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/custom_estimators#train) to define custom estimators, it's shown how to use the `AdagradOptimizer`:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
```

However, the API of the `ScipyOptimizerInterface` is as follows:

```
optimizer = ScipyOptimizerInterface(loss, options={'maxiter': 100})

with tf.Session() as session:
    optimizer.minimize(session)
```

Taking a full example:

```
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np


def _custom_model_fn(features, labels, mode, feature_columns):

    predictions = tf.feature_column.linear_model(features, feature_columns)
    predictions = tf.reshape(predictions, [-1])

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        predictions = {'predictions': predictions}
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions)

    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=labels, predictions=predictions,
                                        reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.SUM_BY_NONZERO_WEIGHTS)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=metrics)

    # Create training op.
    assert mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN

    # train_op = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(loss, options={'maxiter': 10})

    optimizer = tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(learning_rate=1.)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode,
                                      predictions=predictions,
                                      loss=loss,
                                      train_op=train_op)

class MyRegressor(tf.estimator.Estimator):
    def __init__(self, feature_columns, model_dir=None, config=None):

        def _model_fn(features, labels, mode, config):
            return _custom_model_fn(features, labels, mode, feature_columns)

        super(MyRegressor, self).__init__(model_fn=_model_fn)

# Load the diabetes dataset
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
diabetes_X = diabetes.data[:, np.newaxis, 2]
diabetes_y = diabetes.target

# Create the custom estimator and train it
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('x')]
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={'x': np.array(diabetes.data[:, 2])},
    y=np.array(diabetes.target),
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True)
myregressor = MyRegressor(feature_columns)
myregressor.train(train_input_fn, steps=10000)
```

If I un-comment the line to use the `ScipyOptimizer` instead, I obviously get an error as follows

```
TypeError: train_op must be Operation or Tensor, given: <tensorflow.contrib.opt.python.training.external_optimizer.ScipyOptimizerInterface object
```

Is there an easy way to use the Scipy optimizer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be as easy as you wrote. What is your code and what error message are you getting?